# How to install python-devel when using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

Before asking my question, let me introduce my computing environment first.

- OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.5.
- Python: Python 2.6 (by rpm install), Python 2.7 (based on virtualenv)

Question:

I want to install a library that requires python-devel.  However, when using

```
    yum install python-devel
```

The system installs python-devel-2.6.*, because the installed (yum-packaged) python is version 2.6.  My question is , how to install python-devel that matches the version of the python in virtualenv (which is version 2.7 in my case).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This question has nothing to do with pip or virtualenv. python-dev is a Linux system package, not something you install with pip. You just need to explicitly install python-devel-2.7 - you can search your distribution's package repository for the exact package name.

Comment: The (yum-packaged) python-devel-2.7 depends on (yum-packaged) python-2.7, which is not installed in my system.  I guess I can always install python-devel-2.7 from source, but I want to know if there are any other ways.  Thanks!